# Distributed pareto set computation

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, p2p, distributed-computing, aggregation

I have a question regarding distributed computation of pareto front. What I have is a collections of (heterogeneous) computers in a P2P distributed fashion and they all have the same copy of a simple multi-objective meta-heuristic implementation program. The question is, how can I have an accurate system wide perception of the pareto front? Each peer computes their own local pareto front and I need to aggregate them into a one global set.

First, I was thinking in a gossip protocol to let the peers eventually sync and have the same set, but I think that will degrade the performance (It will be slow?). Then, I had another idea where each peer will broadcast any new element of his local set, and of course listen for other peers broadcasts so they can update their local set, and eventually every peer will have the same pareto set. But in this case I believe that will hurt the subyacent network due the increased packet traffic.

Those are the options I've figured out, but I want to know if there are other techniques that I am not aware of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When does the aggregation occur? Is it an ongoing process along with the local computations or is it an aggregation of the results at the end of the algorithm?

Comment: Well, what i need is a real time view of the global set. There will be peers that produces values faster than other, so I don't want them to stop and wait for slower peers to synchronize. The aggregation can't occur at the end because the global set is evaluated to determine when the peers must stop.

Comment: I think that the options you propose quite cover it. The only alternative I can think of is setting up distingushed aggregation nodes, so the computation nodes can just ask and there for the current Pareto set and post their local results; depeding on the size of the network, it may be just one or many synchronized nodes. However, I'm not sure whether it would perform better than a gossip protocol or not.